# Python Column Generation with AVERAGEIF equivalent to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, average

I've poured over StackOverflow and just cant figure this one out. I a data tables with unique letter# combinations, and im trying to get the "averageif" of those values into the second table. Basically, I am trying to generate the "AVG" column below.

```
Letter  Value      Unique   Avg
A1  7.97           A1       5.76
A1  3.56           A2       5.34 
A2  3.16           A3       1.53
A2  9.09           B1       4.55
A2  0.64           B2       5.43
A2  8.48           B3       6.76
A3  1.53
B1  4.55
B2  7.36
B2  3.81
B2  7.30
B2  4.39
B2  4.30
B3  4.61
B3  8.91
```

I've used pd.DataFrame to isolate the unique values in the first data set as a DataFrame of unique values, but I'm really having trouble. I have all the code to pull this data in from a csv, generate the unique values, etc but it doesnt seem relevant. Thanks for any advice, I just cant get passed this step.

Best

Comment: Pretty sure there is a "groupby" type function for that. Probably returns sum by default, but I bet you can change that.

Comment: Hey Coldspeed, sorry if this is a duplicate. Can you please point me to the link and then delete ? Superstew, this was it ! But have to give O.Suleiman the +1 for adding it in Answer format... Thanks to everybody

Comment: Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314424/pandas-using-groupby-to-get-mean-for-each-data-category

Comment: If an answer helped, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do that using `groupby` as follows:

```
df.groupby('Letter').mean()
```

Comment: @SuperStew Vague half-stabs at a solution do not count as solutions that can be "stolen".

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no fun allowed eh?

Comment: I'm having more fun thanks to the answer. Thanks Super. And COLDSPEED, I would have found it much easier to understand the question than that explain in the link provided, but thanks either way.