# Python Element-wise AVERAGEIF equivalent to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a `2darray` and for each row, i want to calculate the row's `average` in col `numbers` for the same key (in this case, `key1` & `key2`. Here is simple representation of my problem, and below is what expect to have:

```py
>>> df
Out[3]:
  key1 key2  number
0    a    c     100
1    b    d     200
2    a    a     150
3    a    a     200
```

```py
>>> res
100
200
175 # (150+200)/2
175 # (150+200)/2
```

I know that there is aggregation methods such as `grouby` in `pandas` as per suggestions like in [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336754/python-column-generation-with-averageif-equivalent-to-excel) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314424/pandas-using-groupby-to-get-mean-for-each-data-category), but the `groupby` method will provide unique aggregates, while I intend to cast them to each row.

My current workflow is like below:

1. Get the aggregates by using `groupby('foo').mean()`
2. Then, for each row, map the row's `key` to the aggregates.

For example:

```py
>>> K = df.key1 + df.key2

>>> K
Out[4]:
0    ac
1    bd
2    aa
3    aa
dtype: object

>>> agg = df2.groupby(K).mean()

>>> agg
Out[5]:
    number
aa     175
ac     100
bd     200

>>> avgif = []
... agg = agg.squeeze() # groupby results shape in (n, 1)
... for k in K:
...     avgif.append(agg.at[K])

>>> avgif
Out[6]:
[100, 200, 175, 175]
```

This works fine, but my real problem is that the row can be super many, maybe up to 200k.

Hence, I would love if anyone can share any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by both columns:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['key1','key2'])['number'].transform('mean')
print (df)
  key1 key2  number  new
0    a    c     100  100
1    b    d     200  200
2    a    a     150  175
3    a    a     200  175
```

Also working changed your solution, but suggest separator between like `_`:

```
K = df.key1 + '_' + df.key2
df['new'] = df.groupby(K)['number'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: @izzatd - Glad can help!